# Differentiation and proving

Tags: derivatives

Prove that if the curve $y=\frac{x^3}{3} + px + q$ is tangent to the straight line $y = x$, then $4(p-1)^3 + 9q^2 = 0$

I have differentiated the equation of the curve to get $x^2 + p$ and equated it to $1$.

But i have no idea how to proceed to get the subsequent equation.

Comment: At what point(s) is the curve tangent to the line?

Comment: Root (1-p) and negative root (1-p)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y=\frac{x^3}{3} + px + q$$

Therefore $$y'=x^2 + p $$

Thus the gradient of $y=x$ must be equal to $x^2+p$.

That is $$x^2+p=1$$.

Since $y=x$ at each tangent points $x=\sqrt{1-p}$ and $x=-\sqrt{1-p}$ ,

$$x=\frac{x^3}{3} + px + q$$

$$x^2=\frac{x^4}{3} + px^2 + qx$$

$$(1-p)=\frac{{(1-p)}^2}{3} + p(1-p) + qx$$

$$(1-p)-p(1-p)=\frac{{(1-p)}^2}{3} +  qx$$

$$(1-p)(1-p)=\frac{{(1-p)}^2}{3} +  qx$$

$$(1-p)^2=\frac{{(1-p)}^2}{3} +  qx$$

$$\frac{{2(1-p)}^2}{3} =  qx$$

Thus $$\frac{{4(1-p)}^4}{9} =  q^2x^2$$

$$\frac{{4(1-p)}^4}{9} =  q^2(1-p)$$

For $p \neq 1$ ,

$$4(1-p)^3 =  9q^2$$

$$-4(p-1)^3 =  9q^2$$

$$4(p-1)^3 +  9q^2=0$$